# My inserts in SQL Server are slow for few tables

Tags: sql-server

I have an application which inserts data into tables. I found that for 3 tables the insert of data is really slow. The schema, no. Of records etc are same in stage and my prod environment. But, the slowness is observed in prod.

I checked that index fragmentation is low and stats are up-to-date.

Schema and constraints are the same in stage and prod. But inserts are performing well in stage, but slow in prod.

It's a client's prod so I don't have access to the machine. What should I be checking now? I am planning to observe IO/ disk is good. Any ideas on what queries I should be given to the client to get to the root cause of the slowness?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on what queries I shd be given to client to get to root cause of the slowness.

Typical cause of "slow inserts in prod" is that the log volume has higher latency and you're not batching inserts into transactions.  Without a transaction, each insert statement requires a physical log flush.

The [Session Wait Stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should allow you (or the DBA) to pinpoint the cause of the slowness.  Waits to flush the log file are tracked as WRITELOG waits.  This can also be caused by having a remote synchronous replica using Mirroring or Availibility Groups, which have their own wait types.

Comment: Both stage and prod have same data. They are not in mirroring